# IntellJ idea deploy artifact need copy static file

Tags: java, intellij-idea

A java web application usually need create a artifact to deploy.

For example:
I have a project at `D:\POM\`.
IntellJ always copy `D:\POM\WebRoot` to `D:\POM\out\artifacts\POM_Web_exploded` while deploying.

I wonder if IntellJ could just use `D:\POM\WebRoot`? It would speed up debuging without copying files.

Answer (score 0):

It's the difference between idea and eclipse in design philosophy. And idea will not do the full copy.So when you root path, it will not help a lot.